# Subscribe to topic cordova-plugin-fcm giving FCMPlugin is not defined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I want to allow user to subscribe to multiple topics via a list, So if a user select a item on list I want the user to subscribe to that topic and receive notification. Documentation says:

```
FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('topicExample');
```

But I get

> FCMPlugin is not defined

. I am able to send notifications to default topics.
I am using  in Ionic V1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to access the FCMPlugin object after the device-ready event:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('topicExample');
});
```

It's a bit tedious, but I tend to trace these errors by logging to console the status of the object along the flow of the program:

```
console.debug('defined?: ' + typeof(FCMPlugin));
```

For other debugging strategies see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744948/1786341

Comment: yeah... I just discovered it last week. and works fine... wish I could find this earlier would have saved huge amount of time. thanks by the way